# Sorting filenames uniquely

Tags: awk, sed, grep, filenames

I have searched for the solution but couldn't find answer to my problem.

I have thousands of file in a directory. Filenames are in the below format

```
74687_1543944930857.txt
74687_1543945090451.txt
74687_1543945278047.txt
74687_1543945465203.txt
75282_1543964541818.txt
75282_1543964595523.txt
75308_1543941117138.txt
75308_1543941398049.txt
75308_1543941677699.txt
75308_1543942393359.txt
```

In these filenames, digits before `_` (underscore) determines the id of a user. Like in `75308_1543942393359.txt`, `75308` is the user id. Therefore, in the above example there are 3 users viz. `74687, 75282 and 75308`.

How can I know the total number of users in the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass your output to `grep` and then `sort`:

```
ls -1 | grep -oP "^\d+" | sort | uniq -c
```

Now, you got the sorted data with USER IDs and their count.

Comment: `ls` sorts the output (when not asked not to with `-f`), so the call to `sort` is pointless. I would use `cut -d_ -f1` instead of `grep`, but that's mostly a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` to list the files inside each of the directory and `awk` to uniquely identify the user-ids

```
shopt -s nullglob
printf '%s\n' *.txt | awk -F_ '!unique[$1]++ { print $1 }'
```

and to print the count alone, do

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt | awk -F_ '!unique[$1]++ { count++ } END { print count }'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ typeset -A count
$ for f (<->_*.txt(N)) ((count[${f%%_*}]++))
$ echo $#count users
3 users
$ printf '%s: %s\n' ${(kv)count}
74687: 4
75308: 4
75282: 2
```